# Saving react router component to local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, router

I can't save the local storage on the react router,
always when I refresh it cleans the page
after trying everything I came to a conclusion that it is almost impossible to add local storage to react router.
A React component named "Portfolio" that takes two props: `portfolioItems` and `totalPortfolio`. It renders a table to display a list of portfolio items, such as stocks or investments, and shows the total value of the portfolio.

```
import  { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const Portfolio = ({ portfolioItems, totalPortfolio }) => {
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Purchases</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {portfolioItems.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{item.symbol}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.type}</td>
              <td>{item.quantity}</td>
              <td>{item.subTotal}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <h2 className="total-portfolio-h2">
        Total: <span className="total-portfolio-span">$ {totalPortfolio}</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Portfolio;
import "./index.css";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Consolidated from "./pages/networth_pages/Consolidated";
import Diversification from "./pages/networth_pages/Diversification";
import Holding from "./pages/networth_pages/Holding";
import Debt from "./pages/debt/Debt";
import InvestmentTypesStocks from "./pages/investment_types_pages/InvestmentTypesStocks";
import InvestmentTypesBonds from "./pages/investment_types_pages/InvestmentTypesBonds";
import InvestmentTypesREITs from "./pages/investment_types_pages/InvestmentTypesREITs";
import InvestmentTypesEmergencyFund from "./pages/investment_types_pages/InvestmentTypesEmergencyFund";
import Layout from "./components/layouts/Layout";
import AssetsLayout from "./components/layouts/AssetsLayout";
import Bonds from "./pages/assets_pages/Bonds";
import AssetNotes from "./pages/assets_pages/AssetNotes";
import EmergencyFund from "./pages/assets_pages/EmergencyFund";
import FixedIncome from "./pages/assets_pages/FixedIncome";
import RealEstate from "./pages/assets_pages/RealEstate";
import REITs from "./pages/assets_pages/REITs";
import Stocks from "./pages/assets_pages/Stocks";
import ValueReserve from "./pages/assets_pages/ValueReserve";
import WhereToInvest from "./pages/assets_pages/WhereToInvest";
import NetworthLayout from "./components/layouts/NetworthLayout";
import FinancesLayout from "./components/layouts/FinancesLayout";
import Graphics from "./pages/financial_pages/personal_finances_pages/Graphics";
import NewData from "./pages/financial_pages/personal_finances_pages/NewData";
import IncomevsExpenditure from "./pages/financial_pages/personal_finances_pages/PersonalFinancesDetails";
import PersonalFinancesLayout from "./components/layouts/PersonanFinancesLayout";
import DebtLayout from "./components/layouts/DebtLayout";
import DebtAddNew from "./pages/debt/DebtAddNew";
import DebtGraphics from "./pages/debt/DebtGraphics";
import DebtTable from "./pages/debt/DebtTable";
import TablePersonalFinances from "./pages/financial_pages/personal_finances_pages/TablePersonalFinances";
import InvestmentsLayout from "./components/layouts/InvestmentsLayout";
import Portfolio from "./pages/financial_pages/Portfolio";
import Purchases from "./pages/financial_pages/Purchases";
import Gorillasgram from "./pages/gorillasgram_pages/Gorillasgram";
import GorillasgramLayout from "./components/layouts/Gorrilasgram_layout";
import CreateMemes from "./pages/gorillasgram_pages/CreateMemes";
import CompoundInterest from "./pages/financial_pages/CompoundInterest";

const App = () => {
  const [portfolioItems, setPortfolioItems] = useState([]);

  const addToPortfolio = (item) => {
    setPortfolioItems([...portfolioItems, item]);
  };

  // Function to calculate the total portfolio value
  const calculateTotalPortfolio = () => {
    let total = 0;

    // iterate over portfolio and sum up  subtotal values
    portfolioItems.forEach((item) => {
      total += parseFloat(item.subTotal);
    });

    return total.toFixed(2);
  };

  // Initialize debt data as an empty array
  const [debtData, setDebtData] = useState([]);

  // Function to add a new debt to the debt data
  const addDebt = (newDebt) => {
    setDebtData([...debtData, newDebt]);
  };
  // Function to edit a debt item in the debt data
  const editDebt = (editedDebt, index) => {
    // Create a copy of the debt data array
    const updatedDebtData = [...debtData];
    // Update the debt item at the specified index
    updatedDebtData[index] = editedDebt;
    // Update the state with the modified data
    setDebtData(updatedDebtData);
  };
  // Function to delete a debt item from the debt data
  const deleteDebt = (index) => {
    // Create a copy of the debt data array
    const updatedDebtData = [...debtData];
    // Remove the debt item at the specified index
    updatedDebtData.splice(index, 1);
    // Update the state with the modified data
    setDebtData(updatedDebtData);
  };
  // compound interest

  // personal finances
  // Initialize finances data as an empty array
  const [personalFinanceData, setPersonalFinanceData] = useState([]);

  // Function to add a new finances to the finances data
  const addPersonalFinance = (newPersonalFinance) => {
    setPersonalFinanceData([...personalFinanceData, newPersonalFinance]);
  };
  // Function to edit a personal finance item in the personal finance data
  const editPersonalFinance = (editedFinance, index) => {
    // Create a copy of the personal finance data array
    const updatedFinanceData = [...personalFinanceData];
    // Update the personal finance item at the specified index
    updatedFinanceData[index] = editedFinance;
    // Update the state with the modified data
    setPersonalFinanceData(updatedFinanceData);
  };

  // Function to delete a personal finance item from the personal finance data
  const deletePersonalFinance = (index) => {
    // Create a copy of the personal finance data array
    const updatedFinanceData = [...personalFinanceData];
    // Remove the personal finance item at the specified index
    updatedFinanceData.splice(index, 1);
    // Update the state with the modified data
    setPersonalFinanceData(updatedFinanceData);
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/1" element={<InvestmentTypesStocks />} />
          <Route path="/3" element={<InvestmentTypesBonds />} />
          <Route path="/2" element={<InvestmentTypesREITs />} />
          <Route path="/4" element={<InvestmentTypesEmergencyFund />} />
          <Route path="networth" element={<NetworthLayout />}>
            <Route path="networth" element={<Consolidated />} />
            <Route
              path="networth/diversification/"
              element={<Diversification />}
            />
            <Route path="networth/holding" element={<Holding />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="assets" element={<AssetsLayout />}>
            <Route path="bonds" element={<Bonds />} />
            <Route path="assetnotes" element={<AssetNotes />} />
            <Route path="emergencyfund" element={<EmergencyFund />} />
            <Route path="fixedincome" element={<FixedIncome />} />
            <Route path="realestate" element={<RealEstate />} />
            <Route path="reits" element={<REITs />} />
            <Route path="stocks" element={<Stocks />} />
            <Route path="valuereserve" element={<ValueReserve />} />
            <Route path="wheretoinvest" element={<WhereToInvest />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<FinancesLayout />}>            
            <Route path="finances"  element={<DebtLayout />}>
              <Route              
                path="debt/"               
                element={
                  <Debt
                    debtData={debtData}
                    editDebt={editDebt}
                    deleteDebt={deleteDebt}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="debt/addnewdebt"
                element={<DebtAddNew addDebt={addDebt} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="debt/graphics"
                element={<DebtGraphics debtData={debtData} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="debt/debttable"
                element={<DebtTable debtData={debtData} />}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route path="finances/investments" element={<InvestmentsLayout />}>
              <Route
                path="investments/purchases"
                element={<Purchases addToPortfolio={addToPortfolio} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="investments/portfolio"
                element={
                  <Portfolio
                    portfolioItems={portfolioItems}
                    totalPortfolio={calculateTotalPortfolio()}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="investments/compoundinterest"
                element={<CompoundInterest />}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route  path="finances/personalfinances" element={<PersonalFinancesLayout />}>
              <Route
                path="personalfinances/incomevsexpenditure"
                element={
                  <IncomevsExpenditure
                    personalFinanceData={personalFinanceData}
                    editPersonalFinance={editPersonalFinance}
                    deletePersonalFinance={deletePersonalFinance}
                  />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="personalfinances/newdata"
                element={<NewData addPersonalFinance={addPersonalFinance} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="personalfinances/graphics"
                element={<Graphics personalFinanceData={personalFinanceData} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="personalfinances/tablepersonalfinances"
                element={
                  <TablePersonalFinances
                    personalFinanceData={personalFinanceData}
                  />
                }
              />
            </Route>
          </Route>
          <Route element={<GorillasgramLayout />}>
            <Route path="gorillasgram" element={<Gorillasgram />} />
            <Route path="gorillasgram/creatememes" element={<CreateMemes />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../styles/Investiments.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Purchases = ({ addToPortfolio }) => {
  const apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const endpoint = "https://api.twelvedata.com/quote";
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("AAPL"); // Initialize with AAPL or any default value
  const [stockDataList, setStockDataList] = useState([]);
  const [newStockData, setNewStockData] = useState(null);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (newStockData) {
      setStockDataList([...stockDataList, newStockData]);
      setNewStockData(null);
      setPrice(newStockData.price);
    }
  }, [newStockData, stockDataList]);
  // Function to fetch stock data by symbol
  async function fetchStockData(symbol) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${endpoint}?symbol=${symbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data && data.price !== "No Data") {
        return data;
      } else {
        alert("Company not found");
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      alert("Error fetching data");
      return null;
    }
  }
  // Function to handle adding a new stock to the table
  const handleSeach = async () => {
    const tickerInput = document.getElementById("tickerInput");
    const newSymbol = tickerInput.value.toUpperCase(); // Ensure uppercase symbol
    if (newSymbol) {
      const data = await fetchStockData(newSymbol);
      if (data) {
        if (data.price !== "No Data") {
          const priceResponse = await fetch(
            `https://api.twelvedata.com/price?symbol=${newSymbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`
          );
          const priceData = await priceResponse.json();
          if (priceData.price) {
            const newStock = {
              symbol: newSymbol,
              name: data.name,
              price: priceData.price,
              currency: data.currency,
              exchange: data.exchange,
              quantity: 1, // Initialize quantity to 1
              subTotal: priceData.price, // Initialize subTotal to the price
              type: "stock",
            };
            setStockDataList([...stockDataList, newStock]);
            tickerInput.value = ""; // Clear the input field
          } else {
            alert("Company not found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Company not found");
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="investments-container">
      <h1>Purchases</h1>
      <form className="form-investiments">
        <label htmlFor="tickerInput">Enter Ticker: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="tickerInput"
          defaultValue={symbol}
          placeholder="e.g., AAPL"
        />
        <button
          className="button-add-investiment"
          type="button"
          onClick={handleSeach}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
      <table id="stock-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Exchange</th>
            <th>Adjust Quantity</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
            <th>Add to Portfolio</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {stockDataList.map((stockData, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{stockData.symbol}</td>
              <td>{stockData.name}</td>
              <td>{stockData.price}</td>
              <td>{stockData.currency}</td>
              <td>
                <select                
                  name={`type-${index}`} // Use a unique name for each select element
                  id={`type-${index}`} // Use a unique id for each select element
                  value={stockData.type} // Set the value to stockData.type
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newType = e.target.value;
                    const updatedStockDataList = [...stockDataList];
                    updatedStockDataList[index] = {
                      ...stockData,
                      type: newType,
                    };
                    setStockDataList(updatedStockDataList);
                  }}
                >
                 <option value="stock">Stock</option>
                  <option value="bond">Bond</option>
                  <option value="reit">REIT</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>{stockData.exchange}</td>
              <td>
                <input
                  value={stockData.quantity}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newQuantity = parseFloat(e.target.value) || 0;
                    const newSubTotal =
                      newQuantity * parseFloat(stockData.price);
                    const updatedStockDataList = [...stockDataList];
                    updatedStockDataList[index] = {
                      ...stockData,
                      quantity: newQuantity,
                      subTotal: newSubTotal.toFixed(2),
                    };
                    setStockDataList(updatedStockDataList);
                  }}
                  className="input-quantity-investments"
                  type="number"
                />
              </td>
              <td>{stockData.subTotal}</td>
              <td>
                <Link
                  id="link-portfolio"
                  to={`/finances/investments/investments/portfolio`}
                >
                  <button
                    className="button-add-to-portfolio"
                    onClick={() => {
                      addToPortfolio(stockData);
                    }}
                  >
                    +
                  </button>
                </Link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Purchases;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Portfolio = () => {
  const [portfolioItems, setPortfolioItems] = useState([]);
  const [totalPortfolio, setTotalPortfolio] = useState(0);

  // Function to load portfolio data from local storage
  const loadPortfolioFromLocalStorage = () => {
    const storedPortfolioItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('portfolioItems')) || [];
    const storedTotalPortfolio = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('totalPortfolio')) || 0;

    setPortfolioItems(storedPortfolioItems);
    setTotalPortfolio(storedTotalPortfolio);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Load portfolio data from local storage when the component mounts
    loadPortfolioFromLocalStorage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Purchases</h1>
      {/* ... (rest of your component code) */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Portfolio;


import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../styles/Investments.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Purchases = ({ addToPortfolio }) => {
  // ... (existing code)

  // Function to save the portfolio data to local storage
  const savePortfolioToLocalStorage = (portfolioData) => {
    localStorage.setItem("portfolio", JSON.stringify(portfolioData));
  };

  // Function to load the portfolio data from local storage
  const loadPortfolioFromLocalStorage = () => {
    const storedPortfolio = localStorage.getItem("portfolio");
    if (storedPortfolio) {
      return JSON.parse(storedPortfolio);
    }
    return [];
  };

  // Initialize the portfolio data from local storage when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedPortfolio = loadPortfolioFromLocalStorage();
    setStockDataList(storedPortfolio);
  }, []);

  // Add stock to the portfolio and update local storage
  const addToPortfolioAndUpdateStorage = (stockData) => {
    addToPortfolio(stockData);
    setStockDataList([...stockDataList, stockData]);
    savePortfolioToLocalStorage([...stockDataList, stockData]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="investments-container">
      <h1>Purchases</h1>
      {/* ... (existing code) */}

      {stockDataList.map((stockData, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          {/* ... (existing code) */}
          <td>
            <button
              className="button-add-to-portfolio"
              onClick={() => addToPortfolioAndUpdateStorage(stockData)}
            >
              +
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Purchases;
```